# Convert dictionary containing items and counts to list of items

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to convert a dictionary containing items and counts to list of items

```
items = {"hello": 2, "world": 1}
```

to

```
["hello", "hello", "world"]
```

Please help me how to approach this logic.

Comment: Conceptually, a dictionary does not have order. Is `["world", "hello", "hello"]` also an acceptable output?

Comment: Yes, order doesn't matter !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

items = {"hello": 2, "world": 1}
result = list(Counter(items).elements())
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['hello', 'hello', 'world']
```

Or a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions):

```
result = [key for key, value in items.items() for _ in range(value)]
```